# Instantiating intersection types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a JS library called [Automerge](https://github.com/automerge/automerge). The library contains a type declared as follows:

`type BinaryDocument = Uint8Array & { __binaryDocument: true }`

Notice that `__binaryDocument` is a literal type true.

How do I instantiate such a type nicely?

I ended up with this, which seems overkill:

```
class BinaryDocument extends Uint8Array {
  __binaryDocument: true

  constructor(val: Uint8Array) {
    super(val)
  }

  static from(buffer: Uint8Array): BinaryDocument {
    return new BinaryDocument(buffer)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know enough about "automerge" to know what's going on here, but are you sure *you* are supposed to be instantiating this type at all?  Seems like `__binaryDocument` is a phantom property used for nominal-ish typing and you should stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this library, but that looks more more like [type branding](https://medium.com/@KevinBGreene/surviving-the-typescript-ecosystem-branding-and-type-tagging-6cf6e516523d) than like it describes the actual format of your data.

In short, type branding is a way to cast a value as a type that has a hidden property. This prevents other types that may have the same shape from being used instead. This is done, in some cases, because there may a special procedure for creating that data which needs to be enforced.

This is further supported by the fact that the [the token `__binaryDocument` only appears once](https://github.com/automerge/automerge/search?q=__binaryDocument) in the type declarations in that entire repository, and that's in the typings. That means it's a type-land only construct.

If this is correct, that means that you need to use one of that libraries functions that return a `BinaryDocument` so that it can do whatever special thing it needs to do.

According to the type declarations of that lib, that would be these two functions:

```
function save<T>(doc: Doc<T>): BinaryDocument
```

From: https://github.com/automerge/automerge/blob/d2e7ca2e141de0a72f540ddd738907bcde234183/%40types/automerge/index.d.ts#L68

And:

```
function save(state: BackendState): BinaryDocument
```

From:

https://github.com/automerge/automerge/blob/d2e7ca2e141de0a72f540ddd738907bcde234183/%40types/automerge/index.d.ts#L156

Comment: Yeah, exactly my thoughts when looking at this.

Comment: Yeah, good shout, this definitely looks like type branding. The docs state "Automerge.save(doc) serializes the state of Automerge document doc to a byte array (Uint8Array), which you can write to disk". The problem here is that I need to get a byte array out of a DB and into Automerge.load(). That's why I was trying to instantiate BinaryDocument. Hmm, seems like I'm missing a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: For reference, I've created a GitHub issue https://github.com/automerge/automerge/issues/408 to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a simple cast to `BinaryDocument` is all that is required. In my case, I am using a Buffer, so for some reason I have to double cast `Buffer` -> `Uint8Array` -> `BinaryDocument`. I can already see that TypeScript is going to be fun.

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(dto.document, 'base64')
const document: BinaryDocument = Automerge.load(buffer as Uint8Array as BinaryDocument)
```